# Switching between guns

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I'm trying to make a gun system and everything is working except Switching gun that stored in my GameObject array playerGuns, it always stores it on 0
and when I press another key it disabled every object that created.

I want to make it so when you will press 1-4 key on your keyboard it will switch
between the gun that stored on playerGuns and disables the other gun, you ware holding.

I couldn't find why the problem is happening so please help.

```
public GameObject Player;
public GameObject Showui;
public RectTransform Uirect;

public Material greenQu, blueQu;

public GameObject nameObject;
public GameObject rearityObject;
public GameObject dmgObject;
public GameObject levelObject;

private Text nameText;
private Text rearityText;
private Text dmgText;
private Text levelText;
private Image infoImage;

private Gunsystem gunScript;
private string gunName;
private int index = 0, index2 = 0;
private bool pressed = false, Show = false;

public Gun[] Inventory = new Gun[4];
public GameObject[] playerGuns = new GameObject[4] { null, null, null, null};
public int keyPress = 0;

void Start () {
    gunScript = Player.GetComponent<Gunsystem>();
    infoImage = Showui.GetComponent<Image>();

    //Get text from objects
    nameText = nameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    rearityText = rearityObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    dmgText = dmgObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    levelText = levelObject.GetComponent<Text>();

    gunName = gameObject.name;
    Debug.Log(gunName);
}

private void Update()
{
    KeyCode pickup = KeyCode.E;
    KeyCode key1 = KeyCode.Alpha1;
    KeyCode key2 = KeyCode.Alpha2;
    KeyCode key3 = KeyCode.Alpha3;
    KeyCode key4 = KeyCode.Alpha4;

    //Handling inventory keys
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(key1))
    {
        keyPress = 0;

        if (playerGuns[0] != null && !playerGuns[0].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[0].SetActive(true);
        }

        if (playerGuns[1] != null && playerGuns[1].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[1].SetActive(false);
        }else if (playerGuns[2] != null && playerGuns[2].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[2].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (playerGuns[3] != null && playerGuns[3].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[3].SetActive(false);
        }
    }else if (Input.GetKeyDown(key2))
    {
        keyPress = 1;

        if (playerGuns[1] != null && !playerGuns[1].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[1].SetActive(true);
        }

        if (playerGuns[0] != null && playerGuns[0].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[0].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (playerGuns[2] != null && playerGuns[2].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[2].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (playerGuns[3] != null && playerGuns[3].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[3].SetActive(false);
        }
    }else if (Input.GetKeyDown(key3))
    {
        keyPress = 2;

        if (playerGuns[2] != null && !playerGuns[2].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[2].SetActive(true);
        }

        if (playerGuns[0] != null && playerGuns[0].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[0].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (playerGuns[1] != null && playerGuns[1].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[1].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (playerGuns[3] != null && playerGuns[3].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[3].SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(key4))
    {
        keyPress = 3;

        if (playerGuns[3] != null && !playerGuns[3].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[3].SetActive(true);
        }

        if (playerGuns[0] != null && playerGuns[0].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[0].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (playerGuns[1] != null && playerGuns[1].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[1].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (playerGuns[2] != null && playerGuns[2].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            playerGuns[2].SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    //Pick the gun when key pressed and store it
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(pickup) && Show == true)
    {
        foreach (Gun item in gunScript.gunList)
        {
            if (index2 == Convert.ToInt32(gunName))
            {
                if (item.gunType == "Normal")
                {
                    GameObject temp = GameObject.Find(gameObject.name);
                    playerGuns[keyPress] = Instantiate(temp, Player.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].name = gameObject.name;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].tag = gameObject.tag;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].transform.parent = Player.transform;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].transform.rotation.SetLookRotation(Player.transform.position);

                    //Change rigidbody and disable collider
                    playerGuns[keyPress].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].GetComponent<MeshCollider>().enabled = false;

                    //Store gundata in inventory
                    item.Named = false;
                    Inventory[keyPress] = item;
                    pressed = true;
                }
                else if (item.gunType == "Stride")
                {
                    GameObject temp = GameObject.Find(gameObject.name);
                    playerGuns[keyPress] = Instantiate(temp, Player.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].name = gameObject.name;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].tag = gameObject.tag;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].transform.parent = Player.transform;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].transform.rotation.SetLookRotation(Player.transform.position);

                    //Set rgidbody and disable collider
                    playerGuns[keyPress].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
                    playerGuns[keyPress].GetComponent<MeshCollider>().enabled = false;

                    //Store gundata in inventory
                    item.Named = false;
                    Inventory[keyPress] = item;
                    pressed = true;
                }
            }
            index2++;
        }
        index2 = 0;
    }



}

private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    Vector3 Pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Showui.transform.position = Pos;
    Showui.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 90f, 0.5f);
    gunScript.updateGuns = true;
    Show = true;

    foreach (Gun item in gunScript.gunList)
    {
        if (index == Convert.ToInt32(gunName))
        {
            if(item.gunType == "Normal")
            {
                infoImage.material = greenQu;
            }else if (item.gunType == "Stride")
            {
                infoImage.material = blueQu;
            }

            LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(Uirect);
            if(item.Named != false)
                Showui.SetActive(true);

            nameText.text = "Name: " + item.Name;
            rearityText.text = "Rearity: " + item.gunType;
            dmgText.text = "Damage: " + Mathf.Round(item.Dmg).ToString();
            levelText.text = "Level: " + item.gunLevel.ToString();

            //Debug.Log(item.Name);
            //Debug.Log(item.gunType);
            //Debug.Log(item.Dmg);
            //Debug.Log(item.gunLevel);
        }
        index++;
    }

    index = 0;
}

private void OnMouseExit()
{
    Show = false;
    Showui.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little script that should handle the activation and the deactivation of your four guns.

Hope It helps,

Alex

```
public GameObject[] Guns;

void Start(){
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(Guns[i] == null) Debug.LogError("Gun n°" + i +" is null);        
    }
}

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(Input.KeyCode.Alpha1)){
        setGunActive(1);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(Input.KeyCode.Alpha2)){
        setGunActive(2);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(Input.KeyCode.Alpha3)){
        setGunActive(3);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(Input.KeyCode.Alpha4)){
        setGunActive(4);
    }
}

void setGunActive(int n){
    foreach(GameObject g in Guns){
        g.setActive(false);
    }
    Guns[n].setActive(true);
}
```